# How to extract Image x and y coordinates & image details from PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to extract images x and y coordinates from PDF using PDFBox.

Also looking for images details like id or name.

I tried with "PDFStreamEngine" but not able to get exact position of the images.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try the PrintImageLocations.java example from the source code download?

Comment: In addition to @Tilman's pointer: what exactly do you mean by "id or name" of an image?

Comment: Thanks mkl @mkl Here i m using wkhtmltopdf for convert html to PDF. So html have multiple images with id and name. After convert PDF and trying to extract images from PDF. Is there anyway to get unique identification of images like ID or Name or custom attributes which set in HTML?

Comment: *"Is there anyway to get unique identification of images like ID or Name or custom attributes which set in HTML?"* - There is nothing in PDFs requiring such IDs to be kept. Probably wkhtmltopdf does it nonetheless. If it does so, though, it also is not clear how it does. Thus, the first thing for you to find out is *whether wkhtmltopdf somehow includes such IDs in the PDF, and if it does, how so. Only thereafter it makes sense asking whether PDFBox can retrieve those IDs.

Comment: Please share such a PDF. While images can have a name in PDF, this is usually "Im1", "Im2", etc. But maybe this tool used some unused tag to do what you want. Alternatively, have a look at your PDF with PDFDebugger.

Comment: Thanks mkl and Tilman.

Please refer the below link for HTML(add flag in image tag, which have flag value one) and PFD which generate from the HTML using wkhtmltopdf.

Link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ArimRzuP4x30zM7-r51kBrIKrdZkK6nL

From the PDF, I want place another image on only image1 and image4.

Comment: The resource names of the images are Im11, Im13, Im7 and Im9. You can get the visible image names with text extraction but there is no easy way to connect these with the resource names.

Comment: Yes from the PDFDebugger, i can see image Im11, Im13, Im7 and Im9. Also some other metadata like width and height but there is nothing like custom id as i m looking for image identification.